# Emacs escaping getty

Tags: linux, emacs, getty

I create two virtual serials by

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

in the specific case, I got /dev/pts/9 and /dev/pts/16
I then start screen on one side, in one X terminal, specifically gnome-terminal (for what it matters)

```
 screen /dev/pts/9 9600 vt52
```

and getty on the other side (from root), in another X terminal (again, gnome-terminal)

```
getty pts/16 9600 vt52
```

I then login in the screen terminal.
I can ls, etc. However, when I launch emacs  (inside screen,thus NOT graphical) I get emacs's output on the getty's terminal, instead of inside screen's terminal. How is that possible? How can I fix that?

I do not know if that's related, but when I login I get

```
-bash: cannot set terminal process group (64718): Inappropriate ioctl for device
-bash: no job control in this shell
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was provided by Andres Navarro (https://github.com/AndresNavarro82). It is necessary to use setsid, i.e.

```
sudo setsid getty pts/16 9600 vt52
```